# workaround for python json <= 2.7 datetime serializer not working

Tags: json, serialization, python-2.7

This is a little bit complicated but I try to explain as best as I can.
I have a class called `Event` with two attributes:

```
self.timestamp= datetime.now()
self.data = this is a big dictionary
```

I put all the instances of this class into a list and finally use `json.dumps()` to print the whole list to a file. `json.dumps(self.timeline, indent=4, default=json_handler)`
I am using a python environment where I can install/modify libraries and I only have access to python json <= 2.7.

This is my workaround to handle datetime:

```
# workaround for python json <= 2.7 datetime serializer
def json_handler(obj):
    if hasattr(obj, 'isoformat'):
        return obj.isoformat()
    elif isinstance(obj, event.Event):
        return {obj.__class__.__name__ : obj.data}
    else:
        raise TypeError("Unserializable object {} of type {}".format(obj, type(obj)))
```

and everything seemed to work fine until I noticed that json does not print any timestamp.
Why is that? what is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the serializer encounters your `event.Event` type you're only serializing its `data` attribute skipping the `timestamp` completely. You need to return the timestamp as well somehow. Maybe something like:

```
def json_handler(obj):
    if hasattr(obj, 'isoformat'):
        return obj.isoformat()
    elif isinstance(obj, Event):
        attrs = dict(data=obj.data, timestamp=obj.timestamp)
        return {obj.__class__.__name__: attrs}
    else:
        raise TypeError("Unserializable object {} of type {}".format(obj, type(obj)))
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew that I had to return the time-stamps as well but I did not know how to do it only. I will test this and let you know as well!